# output dimensions Mismatch CAFFE-SSD

Tags: caffe, conv-neural-network

While calculating the dimensions of the [SSD](https://github.com/weiliu89/caffe/tree/ssd) Object Detection pipeline, we found that for the layer named "pool3", with parameters:

```
pooling_param {
pool: MAX
kernel_size: 2
stride: 2
}
```

the input dimensions are 75x75x256 (WxHxC)
and according to the formula: [( Wout = ( Win − kernel + 2*padding )/stride +1)](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/), the output dimension for Width comes out to be, (75-2)/2 = 37.5

However, the paper shows the output size at this point as **38**, same is the output of the following code for this network

```
net.blobs['pool3'].shape
```

the answer seems simple that Caffe framework 'ceils' it but referring to [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/223630/fractional-output-dimensions-of-sliding-windows-convolutions-pooling-etc-in) and [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/238304/how-does-caffe-handle-non-integer-convolution-layer-output-size) as well, it should be 'flooring' and answer should be **37**

So can anyone suggest how Caffe treats these non-integral output sizes ?

Answer (score 0):

There's something called padding. When the output feature map is not a whole number, the input feature map is padded with 0's. That's a standard procedure though it may not be explicitly mentioned.

Comment: padding is not set for this layer and it takes default value of zero